# How to properly use nested conditional Mergefield in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, templates, mail-merge

I want to refer two names in my condition, for example there is at least one `Referral_Name` and if there's a second one put the the second one, `Referral_Name_2`. So far I have the following nested if conditions for the first referral name and it works fine. [image]
which is this as a result:

***I recommend you contact attorney Rob Plent in regard to your potential claim.  Mr. Plent's phone number is (123) 456-7890.***

The final result I'm looking for would be something like:

***I recommend you contact attorney Rob Plent and Dima Bilan in regard to your potential claim.  Mr. Plent's phone number is (123) 456-7890 and Mr. Bilan's phone number is (908) 456-7890.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes a number of things, namely:

- If Referral_Name is empty, you want no output, regardless of the
  value of Referral_Name_2
- If Referral_Name is non-empty, then Referral_Title is non-empty and
  Referral_Phone is non-empty (i.e. you do not want more conditional
  text to cope with the possibilities that Referral_Title and/or
  Referral_Phone are empty)
- The same applies to Referral_Name_2, which has equivalent field names
  Referral_Title_2 and Referral_Phone_2
- The Titles are always stored in a form where putting "'s" for the
  poseessive form makes sense
- The phone numbers always need to be formatted the way you suggest
  (e.g., not international numbers).

  { IF "{ MERGEFIELD Referral_Name }" <> "" "I recommend you contact attorney { MERGEFIELD Referral_Name }{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD Referral_Name_2 }" <> "" " and { MERGEFIELD Referral_Name_2 } } in regard to your potential claim. { MERGEFIELD Referral_Title }'s phone number is { MERGEFIELD Referral_Phone #"(000) 000'-'0000" }{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD Referral_Name_2 }" <> "" " and { MERGEFIELD Referral_Title_2 }'s phone number is { MERGEFIELD Referral_Phone_2 #"(000) 000'-'0000" }" }." "" }

All the {} pairs have to be the special field code braces that you can insert on Windows Word using ctrl-F9.

Personally, I suppose I would favour "contact attorneys Rob Plent and Dima Bilan, if they happen to work together, or "contact attorneys Rob Plent or Dima Bilan" (or perhaps some variation on that) if they do not, and dealing with that kind of thing would complicate this a little more.

As for the double-quote marks, people take differing views about what should be there and whether to remove spaces that are not syntactically required. Personally, I prefer sticking to the pattern shown 
above, but I don't always put in the second outcome (the result if the IF is False). I advise putting the first operand of the comparison in double quotes, because if you don't, and there is a bookmark in your document called (say) "Rob", the results can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your input. I did skip the double quotes as they confuse me big time and it seems to work just the way I want it. Everything looks so nice so far and now the only thing I need to figure out is to change the "attorney" to "attorneys" accordingly.

Comment: At its simplest, attorney{ IF  "{ MERGEFIELD Referral_Name_2 }" <> "" "s" }

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I got as a final result! 
[image: Final result!]

Comment: Just out of interest, does this bit really work the way you want (starting near the middle of line 4)? { IF { MERGEFIELD Referral_Title } = "" "{ MERGEFIELD Referral_Phone at \#"(000) 000'-'0000"}"

Comment: @bibadia Yes! This is the final work and it's working properly! You just have to be extra cautious about the curly braces and the double/single quotes!